# Create Key Under HKLM

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I need to add a key under HKLM for testing my application? But windows does not allow me to create a key under HKLM. I am getting the error message `"Cannot create key: Error writing to the registry."` when I try to create a key under HKLM.

How can I create a key under HKLM?

Comment: What language? Show us the code that is not working?

Comment: @Gabe: I tried to add the key using regedit

Comment: Are you logged in as a user with administrator rights?

Comment: @nithins: yes, I logged in as a user with administrator rights

Comment: What's the key you're trying to create?

Comment: @Gabe: I am trying to create the key "Comm"

Comment: As @nithins points out, you cannot modify/create keys under HKLM if the active user do not have administrative rights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot actually create a direct child of HKU or HKLM. In order to create a subkey of HKLM (as it appears you're trying to do), you have load a registry hive file with an API like [`RegLoadKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724889(v=VS.85).aspx). So where do you get a hive file to load? I believe you need to use [`RegSaveKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724917(v=VS.85).aspx) or similar.

If you don't want to use the APIs, you can use `reg.exe`. Let's say you have a key called `HKLM\Software\Comm` but you want it to be `HKLM\Comm`. You would execute something like:

```
reg save HKLM\Software\Comm comm.hiv
reg load HKLM\Comm comm.hiv
```